# Battery Bar in URxvt?

Tags: shell, terminal, arch-linux, urxvt

I was looking through an ArchLinux thread on URxvt, and I came across a setup at [post #184](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1035434#p1035434) that I am going crazy looking for.

[image]

It looks like there's some kind of battery bar in the PS1, with a bitmap there too.  I'm not all that new to Linux, but I can't find anything on how that's done.

It's fine if it's only for a specific shell, I would just like to know more about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a zsh shell prompt, and Oblique's configs are shared [on github](https://github.com/oblique/configs/blob/master/.zshrc).

The basics of the prompt are:

```
# prompt theme
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='%{$fg[blue]%}[%D{%d/%m/%y} %T]%{$reset_color%} %(!.%{$fg_bold[red]%}.%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@)%m%{$reset_color%} %{$fg[magenta]%}[%(!.%1~.%~)]%{$reset_color%} $(_git_prompt_info)
%{$fg[red]%}>>%{$reset_color%} '
# use battery status only if we are in linux console
if [[ $TERM = linux* ]]; then
    RPROMPT='$(_battery_status)'
fi
```

The battery status is a [separate script](https://github.com/oblique/configs/blob/master/.zsh.d/battery.zsh) and the graphics are created with unicode characters.